# How to create a regular expression that requires 3 forward slashes

Tags: regex, regular-language

I am trying to match urls that have exactly 3 forward slashes in them.
3 or more would work as well, but I am trying to eliminate urls with 2 forward slashes basically.

For example

MATCH
/blah/blah/

NO MATCH
/blah/

Regex language - Unsure since Google Analytics does not [specify](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034324?hl=en). Assume Perl

I am newish to regular expressions. 
I have read guides several times. 
I have tried several things with regex101.com

Comment: What have you tried? Post it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

`^\/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*\/`

[test on repl.it](https://repl.it/Mmyu/0)

Comment: Of course you need to specify what actually you're trying to match. Should it be exactly 3 slashes or at least 3 slashes? Currently it matches at least 3 slashes at the start of the string and doesn't care about rest.

Comment: Either one was fine. The answer you provided of "at least 3" is sufficient, BTW, even thoguh it works in GA, wasnt able to do so in repl.it, but moot point i guess prob since I am not familiare with replit

Comment: You can mark answer as accepted then so it will indicate correct solution in a case if somebody else will have similar question

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
.*/.*/.*/.*
```

(that means anything at the beginning of the line, /, any chars, /, any chars, /, any chars for the rest of the line)

Comment: That does not seem to work, but answer from Flying does. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work. You’ll need to add escapes as needed

`/[^/]*/[^/]*/`

The gist is a slash, 0 or more non slashes, a slash, 0 or more non slashes then a slash. You can tailor it from there if you need start of input and/or other features